# Accept input field value x>0 [ allow float in range 0<x<=1 ]

Tags: javascript, html, angular

My input field should accept all non zero positive value as float. In range ** x > 0**

I don't understand how can I tell html to do that? each time if a try a float to fix minimum (like **0.5**) it will ignore all less than that (like **0.005 < 0.5**).

So how can I allow this wide range ? ( i feel problem with this range :  **0 < x < 1** , other floats in **x >1** are good).

This is what I tried

```
<input type="number" [formControl]="pQuantity" class="form-control" id="qt" placeholder="Enter quantity"
  name="pqt" min="1" step="any" required>
```

Comment: set step = "0.1" for the input element

Comment: @azad it will not cover a wide infinite range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep "min" to be the minimalistic value that you might need. Keep "step" to such a value which covers all the values.

For example: (if the lowest value you take is 0.005)

```
<input type="number" [formControl]="pQuantity" class="form-control" id="qt" placeholder="Enter quantity"
  name="pqt" min="0.005" step="0.001" required>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onkeyup` attribute

```
<input type="number" onkeyup="if(this.value<=0){this.value = 1}">
```

Or you could simply set the min value to something like this `0.0000001`

```
<input type="number" min=0.0000001>
```

Comment: thanks. yeah this is one kind of fix but sometimes i have to get 0.5 as 0.5 (not 1). But this really helped me. I can use this fix in some other cases